# How to preserve PHP variable in HTML form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm trying to insert data into a SQL table with a form, which looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<br>

<form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name: <br><input type="text" name="author"><br>
Comment: <br><textarea name="comment" ROWS=6 COLS=40></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</html>
```

I want it to refresh the page once "submit" is pressed, but my page has a variable `errorid` that I need to be preserved. For example, if the page was `display.php?errorid=123`, refreshing the page only gives me `display.php?errorid=`

I've tried the following two options but I'm so new to PHP that I'm not sure why these don't work either (I'm getting parsing errors):

```
<form name="input" action="display.php?errorid=".$_GET['errorid']" method="post">

<form name="input" action="<?php display.php?errorid=".$_GET['errorid'] ?>" method="post">
```

I can get errorid by doing `$_GET['errorid']` since the page has the variable currently but I don't know how to use PHP within this HTML form to get it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
<form name="input" action="<?php echo "display.php?errorid=".$_GET['errorid'] ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: There is no error handling? It'll trigger a undefined error if the param is not set

Comment: I corrected one if his attempts at the correct syntax. No reason to throw everything at him at the same time :P One step at a time. That syntax will work on most setups anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought echo was only for displaying text (which I guess is what I technically needed it to do in the browser!)

Comment: It is in fact exactly what you're doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, too:

```
<form name="input" action="display.php?errorid=<?php echo $_GET['errorid']; ?>" method="post">
```